# Why can't I fill a selection with color using GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers, selections, fill, bitmap

I am quite new to GIMP.

I created some text and set it along a path. I created a selection with the same shape as my text.

If I try to fill this selection with a color (<kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd></kbd> or <kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd></kbd>) GIMP appears to fill the selection, yet I see no visible color.

Why isn't the color fill visible?

[image]

Comment: When dealing with transparent layers, I often place a temporary layer on the bottom of the layer stack filled with white so I can see what I am doing a little better. I toggle its visibility on and off as needed. Additionally, I like to toggle off (hide) the selection marquee (aka rubber band) so that I can see what is happening. In the GIMP, I think it is "View>Show Selection".

Comment: Make sure the selection is not outside the active layer. If that's not it, could you upload a screenshot of your settings?

Comment: For me, the issue was that my image was in Index mode instead of RGB mode.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track, try this out:

1. Lets call the layer with text as "Text-Layer"
2. Right click on Text-Layer and then click on "Alpha to Selection"
3. After the selection, create a New Layer
4. Make sure you are working in this newly created layer and not any other layer **(!imp)**
5. Now fill the selection with your preferred way
6. Also make sure that newly created layer is above the Text-Layer, so that Text-Layer doesn't hide the fill effect in new layer.

My guess is, you might be missing the 4th step.

Answer (score 0):

Use the paint bucket tool instead of the keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

> "GIMP appears to fill the selection, yet I see no visible color"

uh? If you can't see any change, what makes you think that Gimp did something?

Your layer is possibly alpha-locked, which means that the pixels keep their opacity (in other words, you can only change RGB, and not alpha, by painting). The alpha-lock is the checkerboard icon in the "Lock" line at the top of the layers list:

[image]

Just click it again to reset it (the "set" status of the icon isn't very visible)

Comment: If it wasn't able to do anything, e.g. due to alpha-lock, or the selection being outside the active layer. it really ought to inform the user appropriately, rather than having them continue fumbling around in the dark.

Comment: There are plenty of cases when you indeed want nothing to happen (or so little it is hardly visible).

Comment: Depends how you work.  In my case, the selection was outside the active layer.  But since GIMP silently filled nothing, I wasted considerable time figuring out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I had to right click on the layer I had just created, select Edit Attributes and then set opacity to 100%. For some reason the New Layer functionality created it at 0% opaque and thus invisible.